# How to handle exception thrown in map function of a Kotlin-Result?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to railway oriented programming, started using this amazing library https://github.com/michaelbull/kotlin-result.

My problem is I don't know how to handle errors thrown in the `map` function of the `Result`.

Example:

```
   runCatching { listOf("a", "b") }
      .map { response -> response.first{ it == "c" } } // throws NoSuchElement
      .mapError { ::handleNoSuchElement }
```

Do I have to do a `flatMap` with a `runCatching` in it? Or is there a better alternative? I did not find a `mapCatching` ot `flatMapCatching` function

Comment: This is too much of a contrived example for me to say anything. Assuming this is what you are actually doing, you can replace `first` with `firstOrNull`, and call `toResultOr`on that. This way you don't need `mapError` at all. You'd give what you want the error value to be, as the parameter for `toResultOr`.

Comment: Yes in my use case this is pretty helpful! Thanks. However I could see a few more use cases when I need to write try catch and other "hacks" to handle the errors if I cannot handle it in this framework

Comment: To be honest, I think "`flatMap` with a `runCatching` in it" is totally fine. What's wrong with it? You can write your own `flatMapCatching` extension function if you don't like the lengthiness of that.

Comment: Yes that was my intuition as well, I just thought that a solution already exists for this I just cant find it, but I can understand that it is not the case